# Behat Make Login test in Laravel (Js modal opens for the login form)

Tags: javascript, laravel, behat

Feature: Sign in to the Website
In order to get all the access to the website
As a Visitor
I need to b able to log in to the website

```
Background: 
    Given there are following users:
        |username |email            |plain_password |enabled |
        |admin    |admin@gmail.com  |Admin          |yes     |

Scenario: Login with Username and Password
    Given I am on "/login"
    When i fill in the following :
        |username   |admin|
        |Password   |Admin|
    And I press "Login"
    Then I should be on "/admin"
    And I should see "Logout"
```

This is my scenario.. i am a beginner for BDD.. i dont know how to make this scenario work by coding the ContextFeature methods created by this scenario..

Comment: for simplicity, your modal contains the form, and the form in the end is submitting the form with most probably with POST http method. What I would do is simply post the test username and password directly to the controller.

Comment: if you are interested with this approach, I can help by answering with a concrete example

Comment: Yes please... I am interested in your approach